# Dynamic tableview cell with editable textfield and textview data coming from server end

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

There is a scenario where I need to display data from a JSON in my table view cell with multiple data in the label, text field, text view..etc, after displaying I need to edit the text field and text view data from any cell, and once completed I need to send that values to the server side.

Please note: I do not know how many cells, as the data was fetched from the server end.

Please go through the image for a detailed description. These are the values in the cell like sl.no, date, time, record of the investigation.

I need to update the time and record of investigation in each cell where ever required.

[image: Text field : Time & Textview : Record of investigation.]

In submit button which is at the bottom, I need an array of updated data from each cell.

cellforRowatIndexpath looks like this :

```
    cell.sl.text = "Sl No."
    cell.Date.text = "Date:"
    cell.time.text = "Time:"
    cell.some.text = "Some"
    cell.record.text = "Record"
    cell.txtVw.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    cell.txtVw.layer.borderWidth = 1
    cell.nosl.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1)"
    cell.Datee.text = "28/04/2023"
    cell.timeetxt.text = "12:00"
    cell.somee.text = "Some content"
    cell.txtVw.text = "Some editable text"
    return cell
```

This is how my tableview looks after loading :

[image: After Load]

Please guide me how to modify the time "12:00" to "12:30" and "Some editable text" to "Something" and save it in each cell.

Advance thanks.

Comment: You have given a list of requirements, but you haven't stated exactly what your question is. As it stands, your question is too broad. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. You should show your code and ask a specific question where you have a problem. See [ask]

Answer (score 0):

The code I'm about to paste is a rough draft, but should point you in the right direction. Don't expect this to work if you copy and paste.

```
    //Store your data.
                                                                                                                                      
 struct Item {
        var time: String
        var record: String
    }
    

 class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    // MARK: - Properties
    
    private let textField = UITextField() // or outlet
    private let textView = UITextView() // or outlet
    
    
    var textFieldTextDidChange: ((String?) -> Void)?
    var textViewTextDidChange: ((String?) -> Void)?
    
    // MARK: - Initialization
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        
        // Configure the text field
        textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
        
        textView.delegate = self
        
    }
    
    // MARK: - Actions
    
    @objc private func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
        textFieldTextDidChange?(textField.text)
    }
    
    // MARK: - UITextViewDelegate
    
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        textViewTextDidChange?(textView.text)
    }
}


class TestViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    var dataDictionary = [Int: Item]()
    
    var tableView = UITableView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = CustomCell()
        
        cell.textFieldTextDidChange = { [weak self] text in
            
            dataDictionary[indexPath.row]?.time = text
            
        }
        
        cell.textViewTextDidChange = { [weak self] text in
            self?.dataDictionary[indexPath.row]?.record = text ?? ""
        }
        
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this code and it seems not working, the field data changed once you scrolled to the previous data which was fetched earlier. Anyway, thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of chatGPT, I am able to resolve this.
I am posting here because maybe it help others.

My ViewController class looks like this: -

```
class ViewController{ 
var dataSource: [DataModel] = []
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Fetch data from API
           fetchData()
           
           // Register table view cell
           tableView.register(CustomTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func fetchData() {
        // Simulating API call with hardcoded data
        let apiData = [
            ["id": 1, "title": "Title 1", "description": "Description 1"],
            ["id": 2, "title": "Title 2", "description": "Description 2"],
            ["id": 3, "title": "Title 3", "description": "Description 3"],
            ["id": 1, "title": "Title 1", "description": "Description 1"],
            ["id": 2, "title": "Title 2", "description": "Description 2"],
            ["id": 3, "title": "Title 3", "description": "Description 3"],
            ["id": 1, "title": "Title 1", "description": "Description 1"],
            ["id": 2, "title": "Title 2", "description": "Description 2"],
            ["id": 3, "title": "Title 3", "description": "Description 3"],
            ["id": 1, "title": "Title 1", "description": "Description 1"],
            ["id": 2, "title": "Title 2", "description": "Description 2"],
            ["id": 3, "title": "Title 3", "description": "Description 3"]
        ]
        
        // Parse API data into DataModel objects
        dataSource = apiData.compactMap { DataModel(dictionary: $0) }
        
        // Reload table view
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

// Save button action
@objc func saveButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
       guard let cell = sender.superview?.superview as? CustomTableViewCell,
             let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else {
           return
       }
      
       // Update data source with the latest text from the text field and text view
    let newData = DataModel(id: dataSource[indexPath.row].id,
                            title: cell.titleTextField.text ?? "",
                            description: cell.descriptionTextView.text ?? "")
       dataSource[indexPath.row] = newData
       
       // Reload the table view to reflect the changes
       tableView.reloadData()
   
   }


}


extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 200
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: 
Int) -> Int {
    return dataSource.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", 
for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    
    // Configure the cell
    let data = dataSource[indexPath.row]
    cell.configure(with: data)
    cell.saveButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(saveButtonTapped), 
for: .touchUpInside)
    
    return cell
}
}
}
```

My TableViewCell : --

```
import UIKit

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

let titleTextField: UITextField = {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textField.placeholder = "Title"
        return textField
    }()
    
    let descriptionTextView: UITextView = {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        textView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        return textView
    }()
    
    let saveButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.setTitle("Save", for: .normal)
        return button
    }()
    
    var data: DataModel?
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        setupSubviews()
        setupConstraints()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        
        setupSubviews()
        setupConstraints()
    }
    
    func setupSubviews() {
        contentView.addSubview(titleTextField)
        contentView.addSubview(descriptionTextView)
        contentView.addSubview(saveButton)
    }
    
    func setupConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            titleTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            titleTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 8),
            titleTextField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            titleTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
            
            descriptionTextView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            descriptionTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleTextField.bottomAnchor, constant: 8),
            descriptionTextView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            descriptionTextView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80),
            
            saveButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor),
            saveButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: descriptionTextView.bottomAnchor, constant: 8)
        ])
    }
    
    func configure(with data: DataModel) {
        self.data = data
        titleTextField.text = data.title
        descriptionTextView.text = data.description
    }
}
```

My Model : -

```
import Foundation
struct DataModel {
let id: Int
let title: String
let description: String

init(id: Int, title: String, description: String) {
    self.id = id
    self.title = title
    self.description = description
}

init?(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
    guard let id = dictionary["id"] as? Int,
          let title = dictionary["title"] as? String,
          let description = dictionary["description"] as? String else {
        return nil
    }
    
    self.init(id: id, title: title, description: description)
}
}
```